# I'm after the title of a novel about an adventure set on Pluto

Tags: story-identification

I read an ex-library book in the mid-1980's (so suspect it was written pre-1975) and the story was set on Pluto.

The protagonist was a space pilot who, for a reason I can't remember, lands / crashes on that distant world - and dies ... Only, some time later, to reawake - alive!

It turns out that a great deal of time has passed. And an alien civilisation, living on Pluto, has found the pilot's body. These aliens clone the body, and then duplicate man's mind.

The pilot 'wakes up'- but can't see anything. He's told not to worry. As time passes, he realises something is amiss. It's then that the aliens explain things: while they've successfully duplicated his mind, so far they've not inserted it into the cloned body - so he exists as pure consciousness.

Finally, both body and mind are joined. The man is thankful for being alive. He now sets about living amongst the aliens. But he's drawn to his old ship, and wants to head off to distant Earth ...

My memory of some of the details regarding the plot of this story are hazy, but I've outlined what I can remember. I've no idea when the book was first published, nor what its title is.

Anyone know?

Comment: You're almost certainly looking for the same book as the OP of [this thread](http://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/960913-science-fiction-novel-man-dies-in-decompression-accident-body-found), but it looks like he hasn't found an answer in four years. Let's hope this site can do better!

Comment: The closest I've found is [this short story](http://www.obooksbooks.com/2015/3976.html) by Larry Niven, but I don't think that matches what you're looking for. Ditto with [this book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/776489.Inherit_the_Stars) by James Hogan.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like the 1973 novel [The Tenth Planet](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/941761.The_Tenth_Planet) by Edmund Cooper.  Though they are on a hithero undiscovered Tenth planet called Minerva, not Pluto.

In it a man from 50 centuries in the past has his consciousness revived by the future descendants of humans who leave Earth after a devastating war first to Mars, and when that society collapses they travel further afield in search of a new home, eventually discovering the tenth planet of our solar system.

A full summary with spoilers can be found [here](https://vintage45.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/the-tenth-planet-edmund-cooper-1973/)

> "Overpopulation and melting glaciers kick off the end of Earth. The population gets more and more violent and it’s time to leave for the Moon or Mars. The last spaceship from Earth takes off from Australia. In command is Idris Hamilton. The mission ends in disaster.
>
> Fifty-three hundred plus years later Hamilton wakes up on the tenth planet Minerva just past Pluto. It’s a frozen planet five billion miles from the Sun and everything is underground. Hamilton goes through a combination brain transplant and cloning operation."

In the end of the story:

> a group of volunteers is leaving Minerva the tenth planet in a spaceship kept in mothballs by the founder of the colony.  Perhaps, eventually, the other ships that Garfield Talbot in his wisdom had preserved would follow. Perhaps not. But one, at least would discover whether Earth, the third planet, would bloom again. Suddenly, Idris had begun to believe in magic. When one flower dies, another is born.

Comment: That's great - having checked out what you say, yes "The Tenth Planet" by Edmund Cooper (first published in hardback in 1973 from the looks of it, and re-published in paperback in 1979) is the title I was searching for. I clearly recalled several 'facts' inaccurately (as you say, it wasn't Pluto) ... I was only 10 when I read it! Well, that answers my question - thanks.

Comment: More editions: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9019

Comment: Glad this was it and we could help.  Too, thanks for the correction on publication date. I have updated the answer. If you like this one from Cooper, I might recommend some of his other books including Transit, Sea Horse in the  Sky and Cloud Walker (which was also from 1973 I believe) among others.